# Javascript's onclick event causes the page to reload in IE8, but not in Firefox, Safari,Chrome and Opera?

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8, dom-events

I have an `onclick` event attached to a button.
Clicking the button adds a text box to the target div.

The code is:

```
onclick="return addBlank("param1","param2");
```

The function `addBlank` does not have a return statement.

Clicking on the button behaves as intended in Firefox, Opera, Chrome and Safari - i.e., an empty text box is added to the target div and page is not reloaded.

Clicking on the button in IE8 forces a page reload and doesn't add anything to the target div.

Is there an `onclick` incompatibility that I'm missing here?

I appreciate your taking the time to read this doubt!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add

```
return false;
```

to the end of the function then? It should prevent anything happening as a result of the onclick event.

Answer (score 2):

IE is treating the button as a submit actor (i.e., clicking it submits the form)

The click handler needs to `return false;` to prevent this.

```
function addBlank( p1, p2 )
{
  // stuff
  return false;
}
```

Comment: That's not an IE method - IE would use `event.returnValue = false;`. In this case it's easier to just return false from the handler to prevent default behavior.

Comment: Hi,
I did try this - and it worked in 1 case only. 
In the second case - with a similar function - the page still reloads.
I have tried onclick="return x();", onclick=x(); and x() has a return false statement, and both : onclick=return x(); with x() having a return false statement. None are working. Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm confused - you are saying this didn't work, but marked Geoff's answer (which is the same answer) as accepted?  So did you solve your problem or not?

Comment: I guess he must have missclicked or something. Cause `return: false;` isn't helping me with not reloading the page in IE8..

Comment: Btw I think you should update the answer with your comment - the `event.returnValue = false;` is working fine for me in IE ;) +1